# ls: show file size with thousand separator

Tags: bash, files, ls

Is there some simple way to make `ls` display the file size number with thousand (and million, billion, ...) separator? A sample output should look like this:

```
$ ls -lAF /bin/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 975,488 Dec 30  2012 bash*
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root  31,184 Jul 29  2012 bunzip2*
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root  31,184 Jul 29  2012 bzcat*
```

This would, in my opinion, greatly increase the readability of `ls` output, especially with large files. Without the thousand (and million, billion..) separator, it is almost impossible to correctly read the magnitude of a big file.

Comment: See the first A to the dup. `BLOCK_SIZE="'1" ls -l`.

Comment: `BLOCK_SIZE="'1" ls -l` is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `-h` option to give more "human readable" output:

```
~/Downloads $ ls -lh
total 749840
drwxr-xr-x@  3 brian  staff   102B Jul  6  2006 UnRarX.app
-rw-r--r--@  1 brian  staff   716K Feb  5 09:28 UnRarX_2.2.zip
-rw-r--r--@  1 brian  staff    50K Feb  4 17:18 bookmarks_1_27_14.html
-rw-r--r--@  1 brian  staff    36M Feb  8 23:35 gimp-2.8.10-dmg-1.dmg
-rw-r--r--@  1 brian  staff   328M Feb  6 18:36 googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-a.gz
-rw-r--r--@  1 brian  staff   357K Jan 29 15:58 hist.fil
drwxr-xr-x@ 32 brian  staff   1.1K Feb  4 13:39 protobuf-2.5.0
-rw-r--r--@  1 brian  staff   1.8M Feb  4 13:39 protobuf-2.5.0.tar.bz2
```

Comment: I know about the `-h` option. The problem with it is that `123K` looks not much different from `123M` (optically). I would like to have the numbers' magnitude to be represented by their size.